# How add data to a map in Firestore document Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add key value pairs to a map of maps in a firestore document. You can see the document set up below. The "Bills" map consists of key value pairs representing each bill. Each bill is represented by a map. For example: "Bill 1" consists of key value pairs which represent the name of the item and the cost of the item.

[image]

I want to add key value pairs to the bill. For example, I want to add an item to "Bill 1", so that it consists of both "Bacon: 14" and the other items I add.

Here is the code I have right now. However, this code simply replaces Bacon with the new item I add. It doesn't add the new value to the existing map, simply replaces the entire map (the contents of Bill 1) with the new item and cost.

Here is the current code:

```
  static Future addItemToBill(GroceryItem groceryItem, double cost) async {

    try{

      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

      int currentBillNumber = await getBillCount(currentUser.uid);

      if(currentBillNumber == 0){
        currentBillNumber = 1;
      }

      final DocumentReference documentReference = usersCollection.document(currentUser.uid);

      await documentReference.updateData({
        "Bills.Bill $currentBillNumber": {
          "${groceryItem.itemName}" : cost
        }
      });

    }catch(error){

    }
  }
```

[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrkkk.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show images of code.  Please edit the question, and copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I am new to stack overflow. Will edit the post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess could be better you create a collection of bills inside of each user, then you will have a collection of documents (bills), inside of each document (bill) you create another collection called items and then ou will have a list of documents (items), will be easy to query later i think.

You should have like this:

```
-collection(users)
--document(user)
---collection(bills)
----document(bill)
-----collection(items)
------document(item)
```

Got it?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot I could have collections inside of documents. Let me give this a try

Comment: I think is better a collection, cause you can grow the list of items without pass the limit of a document size.

Answer (score 4):

When you call updateData, Firestore will always replace everything behind each key you provide.  In your case, the key is "Bills/Bill $currentBillNumber", and it will contain only what you provide, replacing what's already there at the given key.

If you want to add something new, your will will have to be specific enough that it does not replace other values.

```
      await documentReference.updateData({
        "Bills.Bill $currentBillNumber.${groceryItem.itemName}": cost
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about having `all bills` as a new, highest level, collection and then use the `userUID` as a key in each bill document?

Then, if you want all the bills for a single user:

```
db.collection('allBills').
.whereEqualTo("userUID", currentUser.uid)
.get()
```

Less nesting of collections and documents.